# firefox addon install.rdf pass data to server on update

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there any chance to pass some data to my server through install.rdf when my Firefox add-on check server for update?

Example:

```
...
<em:updateURL>http://www.site.com/update.php?var=myData</em:updateURL>
...
```

where "myData" is saved in options.xul or in another place like simple-storage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it is quite nasty. The [`AddonManager` will replace](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/3285e030d9c0/toolkit/mozapps/extensions/AddonManager.jsm#l1055) a bunch of predefined and dynamic *properties* in the URL:

- Register a new component implementing `nsIPropertyBag2` (or use an existing implementation, such as `["@mozilla.org/hash-property-bag;1"]`).
- Register your component in the `nsICategoryManager` under the `"extension-update-params"` category.
- Since you mentioned `simple-storage`: restartless add-ons must also unregister their stuff when being unloaded.

There is [a unit test](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/mozapps/extensions/test/xpcshell/test_bug384052.js#49) demonstrating how this stuff works. You of course need to adapt it a bit (if alone for `require("chrome")`.

Comment: awesome, I had no idea you could do that, or how how sketchy it is.

Answer (score 0):

I found one "simple solution" but I dont know if that is also good practice ...

```
var origLink = "http://www.site.net/update.php?var=myData";
var newsLink = "http://www.site.net/update.php?var=" + simplePref.prefs.myData;

const {Cc,Ci,Cu} = require("chrome");

var observer = {
    QueryInterface: function(iid) {
        if (iid.equals(Ci.nsIObserver) || iid.equals(Ci.nsISupports)) return this;
    },
    observe: function(subject, topic, data){
        if (topic == "http-on-modify-request"){
            var channel = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIChannel);
            if (channel.originalURI.spec == origLink) {
                channel.originalURI.spec  = newsLink;
            }
         }
    }
};
var ObsService = Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);
ObsService.addObserver(observer, "http-on-modify-request", false);
```